# How do I use values from external server in app.post function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm finishing my simple app that allows to register user and then login to the shop. The registration part is finished and I already can put new collections and documents into the external mongoDB cluster.

I got stuck at the login part. Let me show you the code.

Here is the function that checks my mongoDB collection if particular user exists. If exists it sets **userExists** to True. **It is global variable**. I guess it's not good, but I couldn't do it placing that variable inside function. Also I want to point out that this finding function works well and it really returns true or false depending if user exists or not.

```
async function checkUser(userData) {
    await dbConnect();
    await _db.db('blackmarket').collection('users').find().toArray(async (err, content) => {

        const foundUser = await content.find(singleuser => singleuser.login === userData.login && singleuser.password === userData.password)

        if (foundUser) {
            usersExists = await true
            console.log(userExists); // if exists it will display true in console, but later than the same value from *app.post('/login')*

        } else if (!foundUser) {
            usersExists = await false;
            console.log(userExists);
        }
    })
}
```

Here is express.js code. When I try to display userExists inside *app.post('/login')* it displays null, only after second login attempt it returns true, because any code that is inside *app.post('/login')* is executed faster than checkUser() function. I must have instant access to that **global variable userExists** from *app.post('/login')* because I will need it in my fetch response later. I guess the problem is with asynchronous nature of what is going there. To be honest I'm not sure if my understanding of **async/await** is good enough. I'm going to study it much deeper later, but as for now I want to understand why it works like this.

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))
app.use(express.static('static'))

app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    registerUser(req.body).catch(console.error);
    res.end();
})

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    checkUser(req.body).catch(console.error)
    //here I want to attach userExists value to response(later)
    console.log(userExists) - here it displays null
    res.end();
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
    console.log('running...');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your 'checkUser' function is a async function, so the program execution moves ahead after calling it and you end up with null value of userExist. You can fix it in this way :

```
   async function checkUser(userData) {
    await dbConnect();
    var content=await _db.db('blackmarket').collection('users').find().toArray();

    const foundUser = await content.find(singleuser => singleuser.login === userData.login && singleuser.password === userData.password)

    if (foundUser) {
      
        console.log(foundUser); 
        return true;
    } else if (!foundUser) {
        console.log(foundUser);
        return false;
    }

}
```

Also you do not need a global variable to achieve this. Change your calling function like this :

```
      app.post('/login',async (req, res) => {
        try{
          var userExist=await checkUser(req.body);
          //here I want to attach userExists value to response(later)
          console.log(userExists)
          res.end();
        }
         catch(error){
            console.log(error)
         }

      })
```

One more suggestion - Encrypt the user password before storing it inside the database instead of storing it directly.

Comment: It returns TypeError: content.find is not a function now :( EDIT :It works ! you've just forgot toArray() method in content declaration

Comment: try it now. I added .toArray() after the call for content.